# SSRS - Repeated values in Matrix

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2015

I am very much a beginner at this, so please pardon my ignorance. I have searched for hours, but don't yet have the experience to have a better idea of precisely what to search for!

I have a data set in SSRS as follows:

```
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |      Subject        |     Student      |
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |      Biology        |    Student A     |
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |      Chemistry      |    Student A     |
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |      Chemistry      |    Student B     |
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |      Physics        |    Student B     |
    |---------------------|------------------|
```

I want to write a matrix which counts all the students who are doing a combination of subjects (eg. Chemistry and Physics).  Currently, my matrix is only counting the number of students in an individual subject, leading to something like this:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|                     |      Biology     |    Chemistry     |     Physics      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|    Biology          |        20        |        0         |        0         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|    Chemistry        |        0         |        36        |        0         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|    Physics          |        0         |        0         |        16        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you share some more information about the current design and grouping you are using to get that result?  Some screenshots/images of the design view could be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

First, your dataset needs to combine subjects as `Subject1` and `Subject2`, for example by joining the table to itself on the `Student` field.

Then, in the matrix, use a row group that groups on `Subject1` and a column group that groups on `Subject2`.

Answer (score 0):

That's easy:
You inner join the map between student and subject with itselfs, but only if the student is the same, but the subject is different.

Then you do CountDistinct on the studentId in the report, doesn't matter if it's from map1 or map2, since it's always the same.

```
;WITH subjects AS 
(
              SELECT 1 AS subject_id, 'Biology' AS subject_name 
    UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS subject_id, 'Chemistry' AS subject_name 
    UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS subject_id, 'Physics' AS subject_name 
)
,students AS 
(
              SELECT 1 AS student_id, 'Student A' AS student_name 
    UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS student_id, 'Student B' AS student_name 
    UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS student_id, 'Student C' AS student_name 
    UNION ALL SELECT 4 AS student_id, 'Student D' AS student_name 
)
,map_student_subject AS 
(
              SELECT 1 AS student_id, 1 AS subject_id 
    UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS student_id, 2 AS subject_id 
    UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS student_id, 2 AS subject_id 
    UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS student_id, 3 AS subject_id 
    UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS student_id, 3 AS subject_id 
    UNION ALL SELECT 4 AS student_id, 3 AS subject_id 
)
SELECT 
     map1.student_id AS map1_student_id 
    ,map1_student.student_name AS map1_student_name 
    ,map1.subject_id AS map1_subject_id
    ,map1_subject.subject_name AS map1_subject_name 

    ,map2.student_id AS map2_student_id 
    ,map2_student.student_name AS map2_student_name 
    ,map2.subject_id AS map2_subject_id
    ,map2_subject.subject_name AS map2_subject_name 
FROM map_student_subject AS map1 

INNER JOIN map_student_subject AS map2 
    ON map2.student_id = map1.student_id 
    AND map2.subject_id <> map1.subject_id 

LEFT JOIN students AS map1_student 
    ON map1_student.student_id = map1.student_id 

LEFT JOIN students AS map2_student 
    ON map2_student.student_id = map2.student_id 

LEFT JOIN subjects AS map1_subject 
    ON map1_subject.subject_id = map1.subject_id 

LEFT JOIN subjects AS map2_subject 
    ON map2_subject.subject_id = map2.subject_id
```

Result: 
[image: Result]

And if you want to list the students that have just one subject as well, you'll need to make a UNION, because just removing the <> will make it impossible to calculate the actual number of students in just one subject:

```
;WITH subjects AS 
(
              SELECT 1 AS subject_id, 'Biology' AS subject_name 
    UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS subject_id, 'Chemistry' AS subject_name 
    UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS subject_id, 'Physics' AS subject_name 
)
,students AS 
(
              SELECT 1 AS student_id, 'Student A' AS student_name 
    UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS student_id, 'Student B' AS student_name 
    UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS student_id, 'Student C' AS student_name 
    UNION ALL SELECT 4 AS student_id, 'Student D' AS student_name 
)
,map_student_subject AS 
(
              SELECT 1 AS student_id, 1 AS subject_id 
    UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS student_id, 2 AS subject_id 
    UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS student_id, 2 AS subject_id 
    UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS student_id, 3 AS subject_id 
    UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS student_id, 3 AS subject_id 
    UNION ALL SELECT 4 AS student_id, 3 AS subject_id 
)
SELECT 
     map1.student_id AS map1_student_id 
    ,map1_student.student_name AS map1_student_name 
    ,map1.subject_id AS map1_subject_id
    ,map1_subject.subject_name AS map1_subject_name 

    ,map2.student_id AS map2_student_id 
    ,map2_student.student_name AS map2_student_name 
    ,map2.subject_id AS map2_subject_id
    ,map2_subject.subject_name AS map2_subject_name 
FROM map_student_subject AS map1 

INNER JOIN map_student_subject AS map2 
    ON map2.student_id = map1.student_id 
    AND map2.subject_id <> map1.subject_id 

LEFT JOIN students AS map1_student 
    ON map1_student.student_id = map1.student_id 

LEFT JOIN students AS map2_student 
    ON map2_student.student_id = map2.student_id 

LEFT JOIN subjects AS map1_subject 
    ON map1_subject.subject_id = map1.subject_id 

LEFT JOIN subjects AS map2_subject 
    ON map2_subject.subject_id = map2.subject_id 


UNION ALL 


SELECT 
     students.student_id  AS map1_student_id 
    ,students.student_name  AS map1_student_name 
    ,MAX(subjects.subject_id) AS map1_subject_id
    ,MAX(subjects.subject_name) AS map1_subject_name 

    ,students.student_id  AS map2_student_id 
    ,students.student_name  AS map2_student_name 
    ,MAX(subjects.subject_id) AS map2_subject_id
    ,MAX(subjects.subject_name) AS map2_subject_name 
FROM map_student_subject 
LEFT JOIN students ON students.student_id = map_student_subject.student_id 
LEFT JOIN subjects ON subjects.subject_id = map_student_subject.subject_id 


GROUP BY 
     students.student_id 
    ,students.student_name 

HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

[image: Double and single subject students]